# Bridging two realms/subscribing one client to multiple realms

Tags: python, autobahn, wamp-protocol, crossbar

I'm looking into designing a WAMP/Crossbar application with two or more realms; one realm would be for backend messaging, while a second would essentially expose a public API to frontend clients. Now, at some point messages need to cross between realms, which would require one client to join two realms and act as a bridge.

Is that feasible at all without a lot of bending over backwards? Or is the design approach flawed from the beginning, and I should rather use specific topic URIs to separate front and backends?

Comment: did you get anywhere with the multiple realms?

Comment: Nope, I've given up on it and am simply using intra-realm conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simplest thing that could possibly work is to open two WAMP clients - one for each realm.